# rqt_graph in ros2 is corrupted after maximizing it

Tags: ros2

After maximizing rqt_graph, it's crashed and I can't contril it.

How can I control the graph from keyboard

[image]

I have unsintalled ros2 humble and re-installed it but the problem still persisits.

I tried the follwoing but no solution:
sudo apt-get remove ros-humble-rqt-graph
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-rqt-graph

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the initial layout of your rqt_graph, so you should reset it to its default state, so, follow these steps:

1- Close the rqt_graph window.

2- Navigate to your ROS configuration directory.

> cd ~/.config/ros.org/

3- Remove the rqt_gui.ini file:

> rm rqt_gui.ini

4- Restart rqt_graph:

> ros2 run rqt_graph rqt_graph